# Using lambda to format Map into String

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

I have a map with `Integer` keys and values. I need to transform it into a `String` with this specific format: `key1 - val1, key2 - val2, key3 - val3`. Now, I'm using `forEach` to format each element, collect them into a List, and then do String.join();

```
List<String> ships = new ArrayList<>(4);
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : damagedMap.entrySet())
{
    ships.add(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
}
result = String.join(",", ships);
```

Is there any shorter way to do it? And it would be good to do it with lambda, because I need some practice using lambdas.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "foo");
        map.put(2, "bar");
        map.put(3, "baz");
        String result = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

To go through the bits in turn:

- `entrySet()` gets an iterable sequence of entries
- `stream()` creates a stream for that iterable
- `map()` converts that stream of entries into a stream of strings of the form "key - value"
- `collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` joins all the entries in the stream into a single string, using `", "` as the separator. [`Collectors.joining`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) is a method which returns a [`Collector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) which can work on an input sequence of strings, giving a result of a single string.

Note that the order is *not* guaranteed here, because `HashMap` isn't ordered. You might want to use `TreeMap` to get the values in key order.

Comment: or `sorted(comparing(Entry::getKey)`

Comment: That's it, thanks! I didn't know, how to apply free lambda-convertion to the map, the only method i have found - `Map.replaceAll`, wich should return value with the type as the origin type.

Comment: @TEXHIK: The key is that you don't want to change the *map* - you want to get a projected sequence of entries.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry, I had formulate my comment incorrectly. I didn't know, how to get new collection, what i want from the map by lambda, i only knew, how to change current map with it.