# Map values collect to string with streams

Tags: java, string, java-8, hashmap

I implemented `toString` for `HashMap` field as following:

```
public class Bar {
    private HashMap<String, Foo> m = null; // Foo is a class with defined toString method

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        final String[] ret = {""};
        m.forEach( (k,v) -> ret[0] += v + eol);
        return ret[0];
    }
}
```

How to implement this function with java 8 streams? The following is a samples of my unsuccessful tryes (just for illustration what I want to)

```
m.values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining()).
m.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.joining()).toString();
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237577/using-lambda-to-format-map-into-string

Comment: Why are you creating an array for `ret` and then only ever using the first element of it? Why not, instead of a `String` array, just use a `String`? Or, better yet, a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @tradeJmark: Actually it made by inellij Idea after error with just using String

Comment: Ah. What IntelliJ is asking you to do here is basically a hack of the language. Luckily, the answer to fixing it to not be a hack is to use a `Stream`, so you're on the right track :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.map` function to transform every `Map.Entry` set to a `String` representation. Using `.map` function you can focus on how each line of an output should look like and after that you can create a result with `.collect(Collectors.joining(eol))` call. Below you can find an example that produces your desired output:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    final String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    return m.values()
            .stream()
            .map(Foo::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(eol));
}
```

Exemplary output:

```
[foo:something1]
[foo:something2]
[foo:something3]
```

#### UPDATE:

It seems like you have changed the desired output. Anyway the whole idea is to provide a function in `.map()` that does the transformation from `Foo` object to its `String` representation. All other parts are still valid.

#### UPDATE 2:

Answer updated to satisfy updated expectations.