# How to extract string from Mono<String> in reactor core

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a `Mono<String>` object in reactor. How can I get a string value from this object?

I know I can do something like below :
For `Mono<String> userName`, I can do,

```
userName.map(System.out::println).
```

But this will directly print the value. I want to store this string value into another variable so that I can pass that variable around to some other functions. How can I extract this value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using lambda to format Map into String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30237714/9318492)

Comment: That link explains working with the map. That is not what I am looking for. I want to extract T from Mono<T>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer the question directly in its simplest form - you use [`Mono.block()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#block--).

But you almost certainly *shouldn't*, as this blocks the thread, defeating the point of using reactor in the first place. You should, instead, call `subscribe()` and then provide a consumer. The consumer will be called asynchronously when the `Mono` emits a value, with that value as a parameter.

There's nothing inherently stopping you just assigning the value to a field of course:

```
mono.subscribe(v -> this.value = v);
```

...but this has very limited usefulness in practice, since you won't know *when* that field will be initialised.

The more *normal* way is to either call the other methods in your subscriber all in one go:

```
mono.subscribe(v -> {
    oneMethodThatNeedsTheValue(v);
    anotherMethodThatNeedsTheValue(v);
});
```

...or to use [`Mono.cache()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache--) and pass it around:

```
class Test {

    void useMonoVal(Mono<String> mono) {
        mono.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("I need to see " + s));
    }

    void anotherMethod(Mono<String> mono) {
        mono.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("I need to talk to " + s));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono myMono = Mono.just("Bob").cache();
        Test t = new Test();
        t.useMonoVal(myMono);
        t.anotherMethod(myMono);
    }

}
```

(The `cache()` method ensures that the `Mono` is only evluated once and then cached for all future subscribers, which is irrelevant when using the `just()` factory of course, but just there for the sake of a complete example.)

To expand, the whole point of using a reactive paradigm (and therefore reactor, and by extension its `Mono` and `Flux` objects) is that it enables you to code in a *non-blocking* way, meaning that the current thread of execution isn't "held up" waiting for the mono to emit a value.

*Side note: I'm not sure it's directly relevant to the question, but you can't do `a.map(System.out::println);` - you probably mean `a.subscribe(System.out::println);`.*

Comment: Thank Micheal for this detailed answer. This cleared my doubt. And yes, you are right, I mean a.subscribe() and not a.map()

Answer (score 0):

*You have to subscribe before getting the string from mono object*

Just have a look at this for more detail [How to get String from Mono<String> in reactive java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179937/how-to-get-string-from-monostring-in-reactive-java)

```
public class MonoT {
        static String x = null;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Mono<String> username = Mono.just("Naren");
            
            username.subscribe(v->{
                x = v;
            }); 
            
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This will work, but is it the only way to get values from Mono? Is it possible to get value directly in a local variable instead of creating a class level static variable. I want to use this type of code at production level and creating static variables for every mono object does not sound like a good solution

Comment: I think other way is to use block(). But even that is not a good solution

Comment: block() ll return the value it holds. When you calling it, it ll block the current thread. Then your program wouldn't reactive. You shouldn't use that. You have to use it in a non-blocking way only